# How to save multiple images from multiple Laravel blade form elements to Laravel

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-blade

I have multiple `{!! Input::File() !!}` in my blade file with sequential `name`s. How can I retrieve the files from blade form?

Here's my controller:

```php
// ServiceController.php
public function saveServiceProgress(Request $request, $id)
{
    $service = Service::find($id);
    
    $rules = $this->generateCustomRules($service);

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }

    $input = $request->all();
    $input_keys = array_keys($input);
    $file_input_keys = $this->getFileInputFromInputs($input_keys);

    // what should I do next?

    // return view('services.index', compact('service'));
}
```

Part of the Blade template looks like this:

```php
// form.blade.php
@foreach ($service->serviceItems as $serviceItem )
//Lots of form before and after this ...
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        BEFORE:
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
        {!! Form::file($serviceItem->item->code."_before") !!}
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

**Update for getFileInputFromInputs()**

```
public function getFileInputFromInputs($input_keys){
    return array_values(array_filter($input_keys, function($key) {
        if (preg_match('/[B-C][0-9]_[a-z]+[12]*/i', $key) == 1)
            return $key;
    }));
}
```

Comment: You want to get all images from all file input in blade. Right? .Can i see getFileInputFromInputs?

Comment: @MaiTruong That is to filter out the string value of the names of those file inputs from the rest of the text inputs. You can see that in the latest update now.